# Why do I get an error when using format strings?

Tags: c#

From an example in a book, it uses formatted strings with alignment to print a table however the last argument throws an exception.

```cs
WriteLine( format: "{0, -20} {1, -30} {2, -50} {3, -10}",
           arg0: "Type",
           arg1: "Bytes of memory",
           arg2: "Min",
           arg3: "Max");
```

**Exception:**

Program.cs(28,17): error CS1739: The best overload for 'WriteLine' does not have a parameter named 'arg3' [/...]

Why is this error occurring? Also where can I learn more about string formatting?

Comment: @Luc that would make more sense as I can't find any examples aside from within the book that use this type of formatting. I'll use String.Format instead. Thanks

Comment: _"Why is this error occurring"_: That's what the error message is telling you! _"The best overload for 'WriteLine' does not have a parameter named 'arg3'"_

Comment: I think you may be reading the argument names as parameters, for example: `WriteLine("{0} is {1}m tall", name, height);`. I'm sorry for deleting my previous comment, it didn't really respond to the question.

Comment: That book is setting you up for failure, that's not a great quality of a book..  Console.Writeline() has [overloads](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,bc9961bdca1ac236) to make passing the arguments more efficient than using a *param array*.  That is why naming the parameter, like `arg0:` works.  But the buck stops somewhere, at the overload that takes 4 parameters.  Just delete the parameter names to get the overload you need.  And shop for another book, perhaps.  Well, we all learn from our mistakes :)

Comment: @HansPassant this was not an example from within the book, I was just using the same technique that they used for a string with 3 parameters. The book is "C# 8.0 and .NET Core 3.0 Modern Cross Platform Development" and apart from this issue I have so far found it helpful in learning c# (my second language to python). Do you have any other recommendations?

Comment: We know.  Eventually you'll learn to mistrust any book that has "modern" in the title.  Fwiw, the original C# team fought pretty hard against the named parameter feature, but had to give up at version 4 by popular demand.  Writing COM-interop code without it was brutal.  Languages don't age well when they have to make everybody happy.

Comment: Saying that you should throw a book away because it doesn't hold your hand is ridiculous. The exercise in this books specifically says that you will need to use your search engine skills to find the answer. Learning a language is more than just the books exercises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply: because there is no such method. There is a similar method with arg0-arg2, but not with arg3. There is a params object [] version, but that doesn't use named args. Take away the named part, and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

The errata for the 7th edition of the book corrects this to: "The Write, WriteLine, and Format methods can have up to three numbered arguments, named arg0, arg1, and arg2..." [Errata on book's github site](https://github.com/markjprice/cs11dotnet7/blob/main/docs/errata/errata.md#page-83---formatting-using-numbered-positional-arguments)